# Keras Early Callback with custom condition

Tags: keras, model, conv-neural-network, epoch

I am trying to build a CNN model where I want to introduce custom condition to stop the epoch when that condition gets triggered.

**Like**: if loss<0.5 and val_loss<0.08 and acc>=0.98 and val_acc>=0.95 then the epoch will stop and will save the model.
**
Please help me.**

**I Used**

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
callback=keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss' or 'loss',
                              min_delta=0,
                              patience=6,
                              verbose=0, mode='auto')

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.0001),loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(datagen.flow(X_train,y_train, batch_size = 32) ,epochs = 100,shuffle=True,callbacks=[callback], validation_data = datagen.flow(X_val, y_val))
```

**
Output:**

Not Expected